# How to call delegate when VC is dismissed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

I have two VC. I need to call the delegate function when the 2nd VC is dismissed.

In my 1st VC or main VC I have given the following code in .h file.

```
@interface FirstVC : ....<SecondVCDelegate>
-(void)didDismissViewController:(UIViewController*)vc;
```

But for some reason SecondVCDelegate in this is not detected.

while presenting 2nd VC from first I have given this .m file of 1st VC.

```
SecondVC *optionsVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondVC"];
optionsVC.delegate = self;
optionsVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
optionsVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
[self presentViewController:optionsVC animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

in 2nd VC .h file

```
@protocol SecondVCDelegate <NSObject>
 - (void)didDismissViewController:(UIViewController*)vc;
@end

@interface SecondVC : ...
 @property (nonatomic) id<SecondVCDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

in 2nd VC .m file I have dismissed using the below code

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Could you point out what I did wrong with possible explanation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can call it in completion block of second VC when you are dismissing the view

Comment: @RahulGUsai how??

Comment: where are you calling delegate method in second VC ?

Comment: like [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion::^{ call delegate here }];

Comment: @RahulGUsai I have tried that but I need to dismiss this 2nd VC and segue into new one. But for some reason it didn't work.

Comment: call it before this line : [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: do you want call delegate before VC is dismissed or after VC is dismissed

Comment: @sharadchauhan I didn't get you?

Comment: @RahulGUsai after VC is dismissed

Comment: @ashinasok you want a callback when you are dismissing your VC ot it has to be called when your VC is fully dismissed ?

Comment: then completion block is the perfect place to call delegate method and make sure you have delegate set in VC from which you pushed or segued in the second VC

Comment: @sharadchauhan could you give an e.g.?

Comment: @RahulGUsai could you post an e.g. code of what you are trying to say?

Comment: [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion::^{ Delegate.method }];

Comment: @RahulGUsai what did you mean by delegate method??

Comment: the protocol method

Comment: @RahulGUsai also am getting this error Cannot find protocol declaration for 'SecondVCDelegate'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the working code on xcode 9 :

ViewController.m :

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"
@interface ViewController () <SecondVCDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)action:(id)sender {
    SecondViewController *optionsVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
    optionsVC.delegate = self;
    optionsVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    optionsVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
    [self presentViewController:optionsVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void) didDismissViewController:(UIViewController *)vc{
    NSLog(@"working controller : %@", vc);
}
@end
```

SecondViewController.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol SecondVCDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)didDismissViewController:(UIViewController*)vc;
@end

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
 @property (weak, nonatomic) id<SecondVCDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

SecondViewController.m :

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)didmissAction:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:^{
        [_delegate didDismissViewController:self];
    }];
}

@end
```

Comment: Try to make delegate property as weak. `@property (weak, nonatomic) id<SecondVCDelegate> delegate;` You could avoid retain cycles.

Answer (score 2):

On your 2nd VC .m do like this

First synthesize delegate below implementation

```
@synthesize delegate;
```

after that use it on viewController dismiss:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    [self.delegate didDismissViewController: self];
}];
```

Comment: what does @syntesize do??